# Connection not working for MSSQL server 2008 (Error locating server/instance)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, connection-string

I am new to asp.net mvc3 and trying to get a connection going to a MSSQL server 2008 instance which is not express. Anyway, in the visual studio express I have a connection to the remote database setup already which i can browse from my local machine, however when i do the deployment to the remote machine I get the error :

`provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified`

My local ide connection properties which works look like this :

`Data Source=10.14.144.74;Initial Catalog=iLog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myid;Password=***********`
`.NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server`

The connection string that i am deploying in the web.config to the server is :

`<add name="iLog" 
connectionString="server=10.14.44.74;uid=myid;pwd=***********;database=iLog" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

I have tried using ip\MSSQL which i think is the instance name, I have also tried the different formats for User Name and Password in the connection string but i always get the same error. The only thing i have seen is the reference to sqlbrowser or something like that? Other than that I am completely stumped on what to do next.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried connecting using SQL Management Studio?

Comment: Are you sure the db on live and local resides on the same server? Try changing it to localhost on live server

Comment: Your local IDE connection string looks correct. Why don't you deploy the exact same connection string in the web.config as well? Your deployed connection string does **not** look correct (see the link in my answer).

Comment: I tried using the same connection string in web.config and the web.release.config but still no luck. I also tried using "User ID" reference but that made no difference either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check if the IP is correct, if yes, then this should work.

```
<add name="iLog" connectionString="Data Source=10.14.44.74;User ID=myid;Password=***********;Initial Cataglog=iLog" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: I have tried this connection string but i get exactly the same error message. Is there something different about express that i should be aware of which is stopping the connection to sql server 2008?

Comment: It turns out your were right and it was just the mvc3 framework that was causing me problems. I created a new simple .net page and it connected fine so thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)?

Comment: @Downvoter: why the downvote? The link shows how valid connection strings for SQL Server 2008 should look like. And the connection string in the asker's web.config does **not** look valid.

Comment: Where is the downvote, I have not voted on anything yet as far as I am aware?

Comment: No, that was someone else. You are not able to downvote yet (you need 125 rep for that). The downvote on my answer is still there, but someone else voted it up, so it's zero altogether.

Comment: I upvoted it back, because I think it's helpful and pertinent to this question, even if it doesn't completely solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try giving [user=myid] instead of uid=myid and see if it works